# Insufficient authentication scope error listing Google Classroom Topics

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

Trying to learn to manipulate Classroom using examples from https://yagisanatode.com/2020/05/13/google-apps-script-upload-grades-into-a-google-classroom-coursework-assignment/#Find_the_Course_and_Owner

```
/*******************************************************
 *Returns a list of Topics by name and id
 *
 * param {string} : course ID taken from findCourseAndOwner()
 *
 * returns : an array of students full name, id and email address.
 */
function yagiGetTopics(COURSE_ID){
  
  const topics = Classroom.Courses.Topics.list(COURSE_ID).topic;
  const topicItems = topics.map(item => `${item.name} : ${item.topicId}`);
                                               
  return topicItems;
 
};





function testGetTopics(){
//  const courseID = "57299927845"; 
    const courseID = "119335686849"; 
       
  const topicItems = yagiGetTopics(courseID);
  if (topicItems != null )
    console.log(getTopics(courseID));  
  else
    console.log('no topics for class ', courseID);
};
```

Gets error:

```
 **GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.courses.topics.list failed with error: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.**
at getTopics(getTopics:12:43)
at testGetTopics(getTopics:22:15)
```

My manifest file:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Mexico_City",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Classroom",
      "serviceId": "classroom",
      "version": "v1"
    }, {
      "userSymbol": "Sheets",
      "serviceId": "sheets",
      "version": "v4"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.guardianlinks.students"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.guardianlinks.students.readonly"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.guardianlinks.me.readonly"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.announcements"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.announcements.readonly"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.push-notifications"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

I have Advanced API for Spreadsheet and Classroom enabled. I unenabled and reenabled to force reauthorization.

Other stackflow mentions of this error reference 'credentials' files and 'pickles'. I could not find anything containing 'credentials' on myDrive. The other coders were using Python or something. I am working in vanilla Google Apps Script within their editor and executing on their servers.

Comment: courses.topics.get() requires ttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.topics.readonly. I don't see that in your list. [ref](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.topics/get)

Comment: Thanks that worked. It is not listed in the documentation https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth as of today. I would never have thought to make up my own auth!